# Take a url pattern as input in django

Tags: python, django

say i have a variable :

```
a=['https://www.google.com','https://www.go.com','https://www.ogle.com']
```

i have a Template dome.html:

```
   {%for i in a %}

   <a href=/link/{{a}}>Click</a><br/>

   {%endfor%}
```

I have views.py as bellow:

```
 def someview(request,id):
    do something with input (id)
```

Now i want to configure my urls.py so that it will communicate with my views.py which take {{a}} as input (id).

```
url(r'^/link/(url-regex)',someview , name="someview"),
```

Now i actually want thet url-regex , how i am going to configure it . Kindly help

Comment: May be you could do, `{% for i in a %}  <a href="{{i}}">Click</a><br/> {% endfor %}`

Comment: Its not clear, what you are implying.. Please explain it a little bit further.

Comment: i want {{i}} as input to the function someview(request,id)

Comment: But, `{{ i }}` is not an id, its just uri. Do you want to go to the uri?

Comment: i want u url pattern that will send {{i}} to the someview(request,id) fiunction .  like url(r'^/link/(urlpattern)', someview, name="someview"),

Comment: may be something like `url(r'your_view/(?P<id>https://[\w]+.com)/$', .....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Finally i have got the ans :

You have to save the the Urls in database as and yo have to point out the id

```
    a.append(link.objects.get(links=id1))
```

Then

```
      {%for i in a %}

    <a href=/link/{{a}}>Click</a><br/>   

     {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^link/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$'', views.someview),
]
```

Then in your `views.py`

```
# views.py

def someview(request,id):
    do something with input (id)
```

This is a very common pattern that is [explained thoroughly by the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/), so I recommend reviewing that.

Comment: ( http://localhost/link/https://google.com )   this is what i am expecting . what will be the url regex to configure it . i dont want id (which is a numerical value )

Comment: that's not a valid URL, you can't pass that as an argument. are the links like `http://google.com` stored in your database?

Comment: No its not stored , thats the problem

Comment: you can encode your url using [`django.utils.http.urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlencode) and decode it at the view level, but shit may break in many different ways and can be a security concern. I can't imagine what your use case is that warrants accepting random URLs from users and passing them to a view... I think you might be too concerned about the solution for what you *think* is your problem that you're missing the forest for the trees, also called [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: yes , after adding this urls to database  , i can get the (id). But it will involve my huge db space .  Is there any way so that i can get the solution without involving the database

Comment: you'd have to describe your entire business case for us to be able to come up with a solution. what are these links for anyway? why are users providing links only to access them later? why does your view need them? can they be represented by a Model? should they?